# Hover dosnt fit in my navigation because every icon has a different size

Tags: css, navigation, mousehover

I'm looking for a solution to this problem: I have a vertical navigation and in this the icons I've used have different sizes but I "fixed" that by resizing them with different IDs. Now I want a :hover effect on them. But because of the different sizes of the icons the hover dosnt fit my navigation border. I want them do behave like this: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_dark_portfolio.htm
Can somebody help me with this?

```
  <nav class="hidden-mobile" id="menue">
  <div class="navItem">
  <img src="./img/home_website.png" class="icon" class="current" id="homeicon"><br>
  <a class="icontitle" href="./fotowand.html">HOME</a>
  <div class="after"></div>
</div>
  <div class="navItem">
  <img src="./img/studieninteressierte.png"class="icon"><br>
   <a class="icontitle" href="">STUDIEN-<br>INTERESSIERTE</a>
   <div class="after"></div>
 </div>
  <div class="navItem">
   <img src="./img/studierende.png" class="icon" id="studierendeicon"><br>
   <a class="icontitle" href="">STUDIERENDE</a>
   <div class="after"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="navItem">
  <img src="./img/unternehmen.png" class="icon" id="unternehmenicon"><br>
   <a class="icontitle" href="">UNTERNEHMEN</a>
   <div class="after"></div>
 </div>
   <div class="navItem">
   <img src="./img/kontakt.png" class="icon"><br>
   <a class="icontitle" href="">KONTAKT</a>
   <div class="after"></div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

This is my CSS

```
  .navItem {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.icon {
  width:80px;
}

.after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;

  color: white;

}

.navItem:hover .after {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
 display: block;
 left:0px;
}
```

[Navigation Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg6U0.jpg)

[Navigation Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXG5v.jpg)

Comment: Try setting `width: 100%; height: 100%;` on `.after` element. Also, you [should probably read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) about `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements.

Comment: Thank you for your fast help. I tried width: `'100%; height: 100%;'  but as I said the sizes of the icons are not the same so the hover also isn't the same size on every icon.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="navItem" id="studierendeicon">
   <a class="icontitle" href="" >STUDIERENDE</a>
   <div class="after"></div>
 </div>

#studierendeicon{
background-image: url('./img/studierende.png')
background-position: center center; //change on needs
}
.navItem{
width: 80px;
}
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I posted screenshots of your code running. It dosn't fix my problem.

Comment: i am going to edit my code try adding it to the solution, see what happens

Comment: Tried that in this case the hover dosn't covers all my icon titles. want them to take 100% of the width of the navigation box

Comment: I made it! :) Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate  it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. You need to remove the width and height which you have specified `after` class.
2. You can directly give `:hover` of `navItem`.

Attached working copy.

```css
.navItem {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.icon {
  width:80px;
}

.after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
 
  display: none;
  text-align: center;

  color: white;

}


.navItem:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
```

```html
<nav class="hidden-mobile" id="menue">
  <div class="navItem">
  <img src="./img/home_website.png" class="icon" class="current" id="homeicon"><br>
  <a class="icontitle" href="./fotowand.html">HOME</a>
  <div class="after"></div>
</div>
  <div class="navItem">
  <img src="./img/studieninteressierte.png"class="icon"><br>
   <a class="icontitle" href="">STUDIEN-<br>INTERESSIERTE</a>
   <div class="after"></div>
 </div>
  <div class="navItem">
   <img src="./img/studierende.png" class="icon" id="studierendeicon"><br>
   <a class="icontitle" href="">STUDIERENDE</a>
   <div class="after"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="navItem">
  <img src="./img/unternehmen.png" class="icon" id="unternehmenicon"><br>
   <a class="icontitle" href="">UNTERNEHMEN</a>
   <div class="after"></div>
 </div>
   <div class="navItem">
   <img src="./img/kontakt.png" class="icon"><br>
   <a class="icontitle" href="">KONTAKT</a>
   <div class="after"></div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

I hope this will be helpful to you. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help! :) I added some screenshots in my question and I used your code but it dosnt fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a transform effect on hover.

```
.navItem:hover{
   transform: scale(2);
}
```

```css
.navItem {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.icon {
  width:80px;
}

.after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
 
  display: none;
  text-align: center;

  color: white;

}


.navItem:hover {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<nav class="hidden-mobile" id="menue">
  <div class="navItem">
  <img src="./img/home_website.png" class="icon" class="current" id="homeicon"><br>
  <a class="icontitle" href="./fotowand.html">HOME</a>
  <div class="after"></div>
</div>
  <div class="navItem">
  <img src="./img/studieninteressierte.png"class="icon"><br>
   <a class="icontitle" href="">STUDIEN-<br>INTERESSIERTE</a>
   <div class="after"></div>
 </div>
  <div class="navItem">
   <img src="./img/studierende.png" class="icon" id="studierendeicon"><br>
   <a class="icontitle" href="">STUDIERENDE</a>
   <div class="after"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="navItem">
  <img src="./img/unternehmen.png" class="icon" id="unternehmenicon"><br>
   <a class="icontitle" href="">UNTERNEHMEN</a>
   <div class="after"></div>
 </div>
   <div class="navItem">
   <img src="./img/kontakt.png" class="icon"><br>
   <a class="icontitle" href="">KONTAKT</a>
   <div class="after"></div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: That's a really nice idea! I would love that but in that case when the icon gets bigger it overflows my navigation box. Already put the transform property to scale(1.5) but in this case you can see that the hovers dont fit into the navigation (dont fill)  and that they have different sizes.

Comment: I made it! :) Also used your code. Thank you so much

Comment: Please, upvote if it helped or accept the answer if it was the solution to your problem.